# PHP code not displaying multiple images when uploaded

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have converted this code from a single image upload and have tried to allow it to upload multiple images but it only displays one image when the form is submitted.

```
foreach($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
    $temp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    //$fileName = $_FILES["images"]["fileName"][$img];
    $fileName = $pdo->lastInsertId() . '.jpg';

    if(empty($temp))
    {
        break;
    }
    move_uploaded_file($temp, '../images/cars/' . $fileName);
}
```

Comment: `$pdo->lastInsertId()` kinda depends upon you having INSERTED something into a database. I SEE NO DATABASE

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is not actually sending any images to a database, the way this was created is that it uploads images into the cars folder inside the images directory and it uploads it by adding +1 to the last uploaded image so if it was 3.jpg the next image would be 4.jpg

Comment: Then `$fileName` has no value

Answer (score -1):

you just need to use the instruction continue in this case.

```
if (empty($temp)) {
    continue;
 }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

With break you're  stopping the foreach.

Comment: I changed it to 'continue', and it still only uploaded 1 image even though I selected 4

Comment: Thats exactly what you do not want to do